# Access 2013 - VBA - Recordset Insert getting ID

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

Similar questions have been asked before and I've done a lot of searching but have found no suitable solution.

**Context:** I have an access database which contains lots of VBA in place for dealing with button presses, forms etc. The database is a multi user system and previously SharePoint lists were used to sync data between all the different instanced.

We have migrated away from SharePoint to a MySQL database as we intend to integrate other applications with the database which don't play well with SharePoint.

**Note:** This isn't the only time this code appears.  So being able to fix it globally rather than implementing stored procedures and the like would be preferable:

**The Code:**

```
Private Sub Command102_Click()
    Dim myID As Long
    Dim R As Recordset
    Set R = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM `Awesome Table`") 'An Access Linked Table
        R.AddNew
        R![DateField 3] = Now
        R.Update
        R.Bookmark = R.LastModified
        myID = R!ID ' Causes Error
        R.Close
    Set R = Nothing
    DoCmd.OpenForm "awesomeForm", acNormal, , "[ID] = " & myID, acFormEdit
End Sub
```

**The error:**

> Runtime error '3167': Record is deleted

It appears that Access isn't committing the insert record and getting the new ID correctly.

**System Details:**
Client
 - Windows 7
 - Access 2013
 - ODBC driver version 5.3
Server
 - MySQL 5.5
 - Ubuntu 14.01.1

SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL is enabled at the configuartion for the linked tables on Access

Not having to edit code would be a massive bonus as this is a large database with many insert statements relying on this.

Comment: So, just for clarification, 'AwesomeTable' is actually a MySQL-linked table through Access?

Comment: yes, it is - update op

Comment: Is ID and DateField 3 the only key fields on the table? Is ID an autoincrement field? Did you try selecting max ID and then adding 1 to it?

Comment: The PK is ID, there are many other fields; DateField 3 is not a key

Comment: When, exactly, does the "Record is Deleted" fire? When you access the LastModified property, or the ID property?

Comment: myID = R!ID is the line causing the error - updated OP

Comment: Are you sure that the datatypes for ID in your Access front-end table and the actual MySQL table match up properly? Int vs Long etc.

Comment: You've got to do another select to get R!ID. Store your Now() in another variable and use that to select your new record.

Comment: In access the type is Number, in SQL it is INT(11)

Comment: Based off of the information found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172339 I think that BCole is correct, it seems like you need to refresh the data after doing the insert in order to gain access to the new R!ID.

Comment: The issues is I want to avoid editing the code if poss because there are hundreds of insert statements all over the place.

Comment: Aha - hang on a sec - that may be your issue! I'm not sure about mySql datatypes  but I would make sure that INt(11) in mySql maps properly to a Number in Access or the conflict can definitely manifest itself with the "Record is Deleted" error. That is, make sure the Access datatype for the ID column is a four-byte integer type - that's what an Int(11) is in mySLQ

Comment: I think that is not the issue, all select queries are working fine and changing the MYSQL datatype to BIGINT/FLOAT has no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Command102_Click()
Dim myID As Long
Dim R As Recordset
Dim dtNow as variant
Set R = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Awesome Table]", dbOpenDynaset) 'Jet doesn't like tick marks.
    R.AddNew
    dtNow = Now()
    R![DateField 3] = dtNow
    R.Update
    'R.Bookmark = R.LastModified
    R.Close
  Set R = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenForm "awesomeForm", acNormal, , "[DateField 3] = #" & dtNow & "#", acFormEdit
EndSub
```

Now() returns seconds too so the likelihood of a collision is small - although if you are in a high throughput multiuser environment, this may be an issue. But even that can be mitigated by making [Datefield 3] a unique value field and simply looping until the .AddNew is successful. You can add a Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) if you are really anal about it.

Comment: This is causing an error to occur at R.Update: Error '3146': OBDC --call failed

Comment: Check your MySQL datatype for [DateField 3] and also make sure you don't have other required fields. You'll probably need it to be CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Awesome Table]", dbOpenDynaset) too.